# ¿Cómo extraer algunos datos desde un arreglo basado en otro arreglo?

Tags: javascript

no tengo experiencia en JavaScript y estoy intentando extraer algunos datos de un array pero recorriendo los datos de otro. Por ejemplo:
Recorriendo el Array1, encontrar el correspondiente en Array2 y volcarlo en el Array destino
Gracias de antemano.

```
array1
['15', '23'] (id es caracter)
 
array2
{ID: 12, DESC: 'Article 12'} (id es numerico)
{ID: 15, DESC: 'Article 15'}
{ID: 23, DESC: 'Article 23'}
{ID: 71, DESC: 'Article 71'}
...
 
target array
{value: 15, text: 'Article 15'}
{value: 23, text 'Article 23'}
```

Comment: Hola. Este sitio es en español. Considera traducir la pregunta pulsando en [edit], o bien plantearla en el sitio en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer el primer arreglo con un `forEach()` y para cada Id, buscar el elemento correspondiente en el segundo array con la función `find()`, comparando el ID de cada objeto del segundo arreglo con el id del primero, convertido a número. Para lograr dicha conversión, de cadena a número, puedes valerte del *type cast* `Number()`.

Si se encuentra, añadir el elemento al arreglo de destino.

```js
const array1 = ['15', '23'];
const array2 = [
    {ID: 12, DESC: 'Article 12'}
  , {ID: 15, DESC: 'Article 15'}
  , {ID: 23, DESC: 'Article 23'}
  , {ID: 71, DESC: 'Article 71'}
];
var targetArray = [];

array1.forEach(id => {
  let nId = Number(id);
  let found = array2.find(element => element.ID == nId);
  if (found) targetArray.push(found);
});

console.log(targetArray);
```

Esta conversión, sin embargo, puede hacerla automáticamente el javascript. En lo personal no me gusta, pero ya que lo hace, no puedo dejar de mencionarlo, el código podría ser más simple así:

```js
const array1 = ['15', '23'];
const array2 = [
    {ID: 12, DESC: 'Article 12'}
  , {ID: 15, DESC: 'Article 15'}
  , {ID: 23, DESC: 'Article 23'}
  , {ID: 71, DESC: 'Article 71'}
];
var targetArray = [];

array1.forEach(id => {
  let found = array2.find(element => element.ID == id);
  if (found) targetArray.push(found);
});

console.log(targetArray);
```

He dejado el código en *snippets*, por lo que puedes probarlo directamente en esta respuesta haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar* de cada uno.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido muy util.